# ncurses chgat function messes up line graphics/acs characters

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses

My ncurses program uses `addch` to draw line graphics with ACS characters. For example, `addch(ACS_VLINE)`. Then, I use `chgat` to change the attributes there (specifically, I make the character bold and change the color pair). However, when that happens, the line character that was on the screen is replaced with a letter. The vertical line is replaced with `x`, for example. Looking at [this page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics), it seems like it's replacing the line character with the `acsc char` that it corresponds to. How do I make it not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did same bug. You lost an attribute `A_ALTCHARSET`. Special characters are some "normal" characters with attribute `A_ALTCHARSET`. When you masc this attribute (or if you do reset of this flag), then you see normal chars. You need to read original attribute, and if it uses `A_ALTCHARSET` you need it set again:

```
                if (mvwinch(menu->shadow_window, i, j) & A_ALTCHARSET)
                    mvwchgat(menu->shadow_window, i, j, 1,
                                shadow_attr | A_ALTCHARSET,
                                config->menu_shadow_cpn,
                                NULL);
                else
                    mvwchgat(menu->shadow_window, i, j, 1,
                                shadow_attr,
                                config->menu_shadow_cpn,
                                NULL);
```

Comment: This works but now it replaces some normal characters with a `+`. Is there a way for it not to do this?

Comment: @vityavv - I updated my answer